# Change ion-android-star-outline to ion-android-star on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried using `onClick` but not sure what function to go with it. I am not able to make it clickable.

```
<i className="ion-android-star-outline" ></i>
```

I used an `<i>` tag.  How should I proceed from here?

Comment: <i className="ion-android-star-outline" ></i>

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this ?

```js
$('i').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("ion-android-star-outline ion-android-star");
});
```

```css
i{
  font-size: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i class="ion-android-star-outline"></i>
```